# Как правильно заархитектурить экшен NGRX с двумя логическими шагами?

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs

Есть такая структура стора

```
{
    currentItem: 89,
    items: [77, 89, 99]
}
```

и нужно написать такой экшен:
NavigateToFirst, Результатом которго будет такое состояние стора:

```
{
    currentItem: 77,
    items: [77, 89, 99]
}
```

Это две операции, найти первый, изменить значение. Я могу найти первое значнеие и присвоить currentItem прямиком в редюсере или же заниматься этим в эффекте. Или может есть еще какие то вариант? Как сделать лучше?

Comment: мне кажется у тебя в принципе мисконцепшн по поводу redux, да слово "заархитектурить" ни к селу ни к городу :DD. Если ты считаешь что ты это должен делать в эффекте, то ты еще не знаешь для чего нужны эффекты, поэтому не беги впереди паровоза и изучай основы, это намного рентабельнее! все что ты описал делается одной-двумя строчками кода в редьюсере, не знаю почему это вызвало такие трудности у тебя

Comment: `NavigateToFirst.action: 
   return {
       ...state,
       currentItem: state.items[0]
    } `

Вот так имеете ввиду?

Comment: молодец :) но я ведь не знаю какая задача стоит перед тобой. Имеется в виду, что если `currentItem` должен равняться именно первому значению массиву, если да, то все верно

Comment: дело в том что я просто увидел решение этой задачи через много-киллометровый эффект. удивился. и решил проверить может я чего-то не понимаю. мое решение как раз было бы таким какое я привел в комментарии, о этом всем я не поведал в условиях задачи чтобы не сколнять отвечающего к своему варианту

Comment: эффекты изучаются на последних стадиях, это сложная концепция, поэтому не забивай сейчас себе голову, познакомься с ядром ngrx поближе